# Estimation of systematic errors using two sets of 3d line segments

Tags: c++, math, statistics, geometry, computational-geometry

> I have set of 3D line segments derived from two different methods.
>   These line segments represent edges of several 3d cubs and polygons.
>
> (1) first set of line segments are derived by doing field
>   measurements.  (2) second set of line segments are derived using two
>   overlapping photographs and constructing 3d lines.
>
> As we all known, there are slight changes of my second line segments
>   with respect to segments in first set. (I am assuming my first set as
>   reference.) I want to estimate the errors of each 3d line segment in
>   order to estimate any systematic patterns in my photographic method. I
>   can not figure out the best method to estimate the errors of my 3d
>   line construction. for example, i am thinking to measure angular
>   difference between corresponding 3dline segments together with their
>   midpoint distances (from each other) to other can be computed.

**does these types of things can be considered as statistical measures?
But, I think this is not enough or can not say any pattern or systematic errors.. (sorry my statistics knowledge is very poor)**

Any suggestions for good measures and method are expecting. thanks.

NoTE: (AS I extract the lines from image data, length of 3D line segments are not equal to line segments measured by field observations.)

Comment: You want the "best" method, but you haven't said what that means; you haven't said what makes one method *better* than another.

Comment: @Beta: sorry, me i cannot figure out any way.. so looking for a good one. sorry for the confuion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would just use the extremities of the segments (since the segment is entierly defined by these extremities) to make some tests.

A first thing that you can do is to collect the differences between your measured extremities and your reconstructed extremities (as vectors) and plot them to see if you can spot a trend.

More preciely, if your measured segments are [A_i,B_i] and your reconstructed segments [P_i,Q_i], you collect the differences A_i-P_i and B_i-Q_i (these are vectors). Now, just plot all these differences on a single plot. Supposing that you are in 2D, if you do not have systematic error, the cloud of points that you see should look like a disk centered in 0. If the disk is not centered in 0, then all your measures have a common bias in that given direction. If the cloud of points looks like an ellipsoid, this means that you have a larger error in one direction. You can just do the same in 3D and you should obtain a sphere (or can project to the x-y, x-z and y-z plans and check for the disk).

A further test could consist in constructing 6D-vectors, whose first 3 components are the A_i-P_i and last components are the B_i-Q_i. Redo the same with this new cloud of points (now you have to project it to 3D or 2D to see the results). This second test can help you in tracking dependancy in the error between the extremities. I would in particular look at the projections on x_1-x_4, x_2-x_5 and x_3-x_6 and see if I obtain disks or not.

Finally, if you really want to have statistical tests, you can take the two clouds of points mentioned above and:

- Check that the mean is not significantly different from 0 using a [t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test)
- Check that there is no major trend using a linear regression and an [ANOVA analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance)

Hope it helps!

EDIT: since you mention C++, for the visualization, you can export your result to a text file (or a CSV) and read it using octave for example.

Comment: first, sorry for my poor math. in my case, for example if i take a corresponding reference and constructed line segment pair; then even though they exactly overlap on top of the other, their end points are not the same (as i said, due to the image base edge extraction), so that I guess, their vectors (in-terms of length) might not be the same.. so I am confusing how to do this. (may be this is bcz of my poor math). any explanation (or examples are appreciated). thanks again.

Comment: If you want to check for a particular systematic error, you can just collect the errors, for your example, the difference between the measured length and the reconstructed length (keep the sign!). Then, plot these errors and see if they are well distributed. You can check also for the average (should be 0 or close) and you can use the t-test as mentioned above for a further check.

Comment: when I am doing the experiment, i got to know that my reference and constructed line segments are not equal. it is due to shadow or some other effects of the images. So, If I used the end point coordinates, then i think I can not recognise any pattern in terms of their orientation. So, If I use the common overlap of respective line pairs, then can I find the difference? If not I think the contributions done by the length of the line will come into our vectors. Actually, I do not want to analyse errors with respect to their lengths. because it is obvious thing.

Comment: I want to find the error pattern how each other orient with respect to other. If no more error in my construction, then it should coincided with reference. any solution please.